# Using multiple DLL's written in C within a C# program

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, dll

I have a program written in C#. I want to use a DLL made in C within this program.

```
public class Test
{
    [DllImport(@"C:/.../surcouche2.dll")]
    public static extern int refreshEntities();
}
```

I call the function as:

```
Test.refreshEntities();
```

I am using Visual Studio. To create the DLL `surcouche2.dll`, I created a new Visual C++ Application Console, then I chose DLL and left the options on their defaults. Then, I told to VS to compile using C.

The function is :

```
__declspec(dllexport) int refreshEntities() {
    int ret = 0;
    LibData *n;

    n = newLibData(LIB_MODULES_MODULE_ENTITES, LIB_MODULES_ACTION_SELECT,
            "http://10.0.2.2:4242/WebService1.asmx");
    if (n)
    {
        ret = n->refreshDb(n);
        n->destroy(n);
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

The functions called in are in another DLL (that is referenced). But I get this error:

```
system.DllNotFoundException: Impossible de charger la DLL 'C:/.../surcouche2.dll': Le module spécifié est introuvable. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007007E)
   à app.Lol.refreshEntities()
   à app.MainWindow..ctor() dans c:\...\MainWindow.xaml.cs:ligne 30
```

But, if I change the function `refreshEntities` like this, then it works fine:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int refreshEntities() {
    return (42);
}
```

The second DLL uses another DLL (both in C). I created them with the option "create an empty project" so I haven't the `stdafx.h`, ... files. I guess it's not a problem because I can use a function from the third DLL in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can happen if a dependency of loaded dll can't be resolved.
First of all I propose you to put both native assemblies in a bin folder and change a reference
from `[DllImport(@"C:/.../surcouche2.dll")]` to `[DllImport("surcouche2.dll")]`

In general to debug dependency issues tools like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can be useful. First helps to understand what the dependencies are, second to check there your application is trying to find the assemplies.

Configure Process Monitor's to show process activity only and apply process name filter with your application name like on the picture below and you will get all files your app trying to access. It will help to find missing dll's.
[image: Process Monitor filtering]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to put the DLL in the executable directory but I have still the same problem. I took a look to Dependency Walker and Process Monitor but I didn't see anything that could help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DllImport(@"C:/.../surcouche2.dll")]
```

This is *bad idea*, you are getting a preview of what is going to go wrong on your user's machine as well.  Hard-coding the path to the DLL like that helps the pinvoke marshaller to find the DLL file on disk.  But it does absolutely nothing to help the operating system to find DLLs that surchouce2.dll needs.  Like the one that contains the newLibData() function.

The error message is often mis-interpreted.  It says it "cannot load" surcouche2.dll.  Which is accurate, but most programmers will read the message as "cannot find" surcouche2.dll.  The most common reason for the exception.  Not the problem here.

Never mess with DLL Hell.  The days that keeping DLLs in a separate directory and sharing them between different programs was useful are long, long gone.  Always copy dependent DLLs into the same directory as the EXE that needs them.  Makes it very easy on the operating system to find them.  And avoids the considerable misery you'll have to deal with when it finds the wrong file.

Use Project + Add Existing Item and select the DLLs.  Set their Copy Local property to True.  If you don't like the clutter then use XCOPY in a post-build event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to put the DLL in the executable directory but I have still the same problem.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see the program searching for the missing DLL and not finding it.  Tells you where it looks, also tells you about a DLL that you might not realize is required.  Like the CRT, very easy to overlook.